# Nodejs child process stdin.write no callback

Tags: node.js

I have spawned a "keep alive" nodejs child process that does things in response to incoming http get request.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = spawn("long_live_exe");

app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
     child.stdin.write("some_request\n");
     res.send("task completed");
 });
```

Ideally, I'd like to send back response, based on `child.stdout`, like this

```
 app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
     child.stdin.write("some_request\n");
     child.stdout.on('data', function(result){
            res.send(result);
     });
 });
```

The problem is that per each request, `stdout.on` event function is wired one more time. Isn't it a bad thing to do?

Somehow, if I can get callback function from `stdin.write`, imagine if I can write code

```
 app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
     child.stdin.write("some_request\n", function(reply){
            res.send(reply); 
      });

 });
```

The question is how to feed `child.stdout.on` back to a http request callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `once` :

```
app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
   child.stdin.write("some_request\n");
   child.stdout.once('data', function(result){
     res.send(result);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to accomplish this is by using a [stream-pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options):

```
app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
  child.stdin.write("some_request\n")
  child.stdout.pipe(res)
})
```

If you need to rely on a single write on the `stdout` emitter use `res.end` insted of `res.send` in order to flush the response right after ;)

```
app.get("/some_request", function(req, res){
  child.stdin.write("some_request\n")
  child.stdout.once('data', res.end)
})
```